# IPrincipal.IsInRole VS PrincipalPermission.Demand?

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication

I have a user with  Principal.

I know that I could check if the user is an Admin via :

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Administrators")`

I also saw this :

```
PrincipalPermission principalPerm = new PrincipalPermission(null, "Administrators");
principalPerm.Demand(); //under a try-catch cntext
```

*From my testing they return same results*

Question :

- Are they the same ?
- If not , when should I use which ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Demand()` call throws an exception, which would propogate up the call stack automatically if not caught, the `IsInRole()` call is a comparison test, which can be used to perform some either-or code.

Are they the same: No, one throws an exception, the other returns a true/false value.

When should I use which: Use `Demand()` if you want to force-terminate processing if you do not have the privilege, use `IsInRole()` to perform conditional processing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Petesh answer, the PrincipalPermission can be imposed declaratively with the PrincipalPermissionAttribute.

This could be a viable alternative if you like a AOP-like validation. The validation code doesn't spoil your business logic and the runtime applies it automatically.

```
[PrincipalPermission(...)]
public void Foo()
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is for at a method level. what about a page level ?

Comment: I don't remember and can be wrong but the attribute should work on both method and class level.